# Associação entre classes com PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Procurei um conteúdo sobre relacionamento entre classes, mais especificamente associação, mas todos os exemplos que eu encontrei não estavam devidamente encapsulados (atributos e métodos declarados como públicos), tentei fazer por mim mesmo uma associação da forma que acredito ser a correta, no entanto quando os objetos são instanciados o PHP retorna erros:

A associação entre duas classes `Produto` e `Fornecedor`:

Classe `Produto`:

```
class Produto {
    private $nome, $valor, $Fornecedor, $id;

    function __construct($nome, $valor, $Fornecedor, $id) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->valor = $valor;
        $this->Fornecedor = $Fornecedor;//Associação
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNome($nome)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    function setValor($valor)
    {
        $this->valor = $valor;
    }

    function getValor()
    {
        return $this->valor;
    }

    function setFornecedor($fornecedor){
        $this->fornecedor = $fornecedor;
    }

    function getFornecedor()
    {
        return $this->Fornecedor;
    }

    function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Classe `Fornecedor`:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Fornecedor
 *
 * @author AbelSouzaCostaJúnior
 */
class Fornecedor {
    private $rs, $id, $endereco, $telefone;//Rs → razão social

    function __construct($rs, $id, $endereco, $telefone) {
        $this->rs = $rs;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    }

    function setRazao($rs)
    {
        $this->rs = $rs;
    }

    function getRazao()
    {
        return $this->rs;
    }

    function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function setEndereco($endereco)
    {
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
    }

    function getEndereco()
    {
        return $this->endereco;
    }

    function setTelefone($telefone)
    {
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    }

    function getTelefone()
    {
        return $this->telefone;
    }
}
```

Instâncias das classes:

```
<?php
    require_once 'Produto.php';
    require_once 'Fornecedor.php';

    $Fornecedor = new Fornecedor("Mercado da Casa", 359, "Rua B", 32210273);
    $Produto = new Produto("Café 250g", 1.99, $Fornecedor, 03331);

    echo "===========================<br>"
    . "Informaçõs sobre o produto<br>"
            . "Código do produto: {$Produto->getId()}"
            . "<br>"
            . "Produto: {$Produto->getNome()}"
            . "<br>"
                    . "Fornecedor: {$Produto->Fornecedor->getRazao()}"   // Linha 26
?>
```

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Fornecedor could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto\index.php on line 26

Gostaria de saber onde eu estou errando.

Comment: Quais são os erros retornados? Aparentemente falta um `;` no final do `echo` das informações do produto.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Fornecedor could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto\index.php on line 26

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione essa informação. Especifique também qual é a linha 26.

Comment: "Fornecedor: {$Produto->$Fornecedor->getRazao()}"; essa é a linha 26, não posso editar perguntas ainda

Comment: A linha que você postou aqui está diferente da do código. Por quê tem esse `$` na frente de `Fornecedor`? Pelo visto você nem postou na pergunta a linha que está dando erro.

Comment: Somente uma tentativa novamente mal sucedida.

Comment: Ok, mas o código que você postou não é o código completo de `index.php`, é? O erro está na linha 26 e você postou apenas 15 linhas.

Comment: Eu peguei somente o que diz, respeito ao php, o resto é html criado automaticamente pelo Netbeans

Comment: Ok. Você definiu o atributo `Fornecedor` como privado e está tentando acessá-lo diretamente? Já tentou utilizar o método `getFornecedor`? Algo como `$Produto->getFornecedor()->getRazao()`? Detalhe: no método `setFornecedor`, o atributo `Fornecedor` está escrito com letra minúscula.

Comment: agora eu consegui, muito obrigado meu amigo, era exatamente isso que eu deveria fazer

Answer (score 0):

Na linha apontada pelo erro

```
. "Fornecedor: {$Produto->Fornecedor->getRazao()}"
```

Corrija dessa forma:

```
. "Fornecedor: {$Produto->getFornecedor()->getRazao()}";
```

Resultado:

```
===========================
Informaçõs sobre o produto
Código do produto: 1753
Produto: Café 250g
Fornecedor: Mercado da Casa
```

Isso deve resolver o problema principal. Apenas acho estranho a mensagem do erro pois é diferente do erro que apareceu no ambiente onde executei. PHP7.1.0 builtin server, Android (app: Server for PHP).

O erro aqui foi por tentar acessar uma propriedade definida como privada. A partir daí ficou óbvio o erro e apenas usei o getter (`getFornecedor()`). E veio a pergunta, “por que ele não usa o getter se o declarou?”. Mas aí já entra em outro assunto.

A resposta deveria acabar aqui, mas citarei outros erros óbvios por precaução.

## Outros pontos

Nesse trecho

```
function setFornecedor($fornecedor){
    $this->fornecedor = $fornecedor;
}
```

A propriedade inicia com letra maiúscula. Deveria ser assim:

```
function setFornecedor($fornecedor){
    $this->Fornecedor = $fornecedor;
}
```

Corrija também a visibilidade das propriedades e métodos pois sem uma definição, as versões atuais do PHP emitem avisos de erros que podem interromper a execução dependendo da configuração do ambiente.

Exemplo:

```
public function blabla() {

}
```